# The same for loop works in other projects, but doesn't work in this project. Why?

Tags: c++, loops

The for loop looks completely correct yet functions as an infinite loop. I can't find the issue.

I tried using a while loop instead and it did the same thing. I copied and pasted the same loop on an empty project and it worked there just as intended. Because of the tweaks I've done, the struct space part is irrelevant. But if I can fix the problem I will use it again.

```
struct space draw(){
    int x,y;
    for(y=0;y<10;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<10;x++){
            cout<<"a ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Loop should write 10"a" s end the line and repeat 10 times in total. It instead writes 10 "a" s ends the line and repeats forever.

Comment: What is struct space? Why does not the function have a return statement wnen its return type is not void?

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with the loops you posted. Perhaps there's something else you're doing that is causing it?

Comment: Testing the problem in a new project is a good first step. Since it works there, the task now is to find out what the critical difference is between the (working) isolated code and the (not working) code in context. One way is to add more and more stuff from the latter to the former until you can reproduce the issue. But we simply can't help you with figuring out the problem in the code that doesn't work if you only show us the code that works.

Comment: @Nakroxis Provide a minimal complete program that reptoduces the problem.

Comment: Did you use a debugger and check that _exactly this loop_ loops inifinitely? Because this code is fine, except for the missing `return`.

Comment: @churill "this code is fine, except for the missing return" - The missing return makes the code absolutely *not fine*. The absence of the `return` statement results in the code having Undefined Behaviour and *any* code the compiler may choose to generate is acceptable. In this case, the loop is irrelevant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ok, I should have been more precise: The loops are fine. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the part I thought was irrelevant was the actual problem. Changing the struct space into void fixed the problem. I should had been more careful. Thank you all.

Answer (score 6):

You've declared the function to return an object of type `space`. Your function does not have a return statement. The behaviour of the program is undefined.